# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in Javascript in Django Template

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm building a **Django Weather App**, where there is a search input field and and by writing city name in input we can get weather details in console for now. But when typing any city name in input form, its showing `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"` error in console. I am unable to debug this error.

models.py

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class CityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ('__all__')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('ajax5',views.ajax5view)
]
```

views.py

```
def ajax5view(request):
    return render (request,'ajax5.html')
```

ajax5.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
   </script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/ajax5.js' %}" type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="GET" action="">
    <span><input type="text"  name='city_name' id="city" placeholder="Search: city_name" value="{{ request.GET.get }}"/></span>

    <span><input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Search" ></span>
    </form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript (ajax5.js)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var city = $('#city').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q='+ city +'&appid=026b9c980571390d69406536cdaaccea',
                method : 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }

            })

    });
});
```

Comment: Please post the *full traceback*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually its rendering the form to the frontend , there is no traceback error but in console it showing ` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier ajax5.js:8`

Comment: Following on from @WillemVanOnsem, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` gives no context to us

Comment: You are missing a comma after the `dataType` line. As a result the `success` identifier clashes with the `'json'` string literal.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks Sir, it solved the syntax error but now a new problem occurred. Though there is no error but its now showing data in console.Is there any additional error in my JavaScript code?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak What did you think `console.log(data);` would do?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: that is not an error. This is what you write: you write as `success` a function that prints it to the console.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Sir i am newbie, just following a tutorial blindly,there it did the above and its showing the fetched data from URL in console but in me its not showing anything.

Comment: @schwobaseggl i think in `console.log(data)` whould show the fetched data from url. and i think im wrong! ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So, its getting data from that url?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: yes. If the data is logged (typically logging is black, errors are red), then it does what you instructed it to do.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But Sir in mine, console showing nothing, what am i doing wrong that its not fetching the data from the url?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak: I mean the console in the *browser*... JavaScript is *frontend*, Django *backend*. You `console.log(..)` in JavaScript so at the *browser*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah Sir, i have tried POST method in Ajax and it shows created object in console.. but it GET method its showing blank.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sir,it worked! i forgot to add preventDefault(), thats why it was refreshing and creating new empty form.. thats why data on console was not showing.. Now its showing complete weather  data.

Answer (score 1):

As corrected by @WillemVanOnsem I added comma in dataType Line and then problem was my form was getting refreshed so data from console was getting erased. Therefore i added `preventDefault()` and my code is working fine. This is my final Ajax Code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
        var $city = $('#city').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q="+$city+"&appid=026b9c980571390d69406536cdaaccea",
                type : 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }

            })

    });
});
```